# Array in C# are reference type, why they acts as a value types?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, c#-4.0

According to MSDN, if all arrays are reference type, then why in the given sample code, the new value of `t2` doesn't reflect the change in `t1`?

```
string[] data = new[] { "One", "Two" };

var t1 = data[0];

Console.WriteLine(t1);

var t2 = t1;
t2 = "Three"; //assigning the new value, and this should reflect in t1

Console.WriteLine(t2);
Console.WriteLine(t1); // this should print 'Three', but it prints 'One'

Console.Read();
```

[image]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301755.aspx

> Arrays are mechanisms that allow you to treat several items as a
>   single collection. The Microsoft® .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR)
>   supports single-dimensional arrays, multidimensional arrays, and
>   jagged arrays (arrays of arrays). All array types are implicitly
>   derived from System.Array, which itself is derived from System.Object.
>   This means that all arrays are always reference types which are
>   allocated on the managed heap, and your app's variable contains a
>   reference to the array and not the array itself.

Comment: To me it looks like you are simply letting `t2` point to another memory location.

Comment: You're confusing changing the content of a variable/field with mutating the data it references.

Comment: The array itself is of course a reference-type, but this does not count for its contained elements. They MAY be reference-types (in case of class-objects), or value-types.

Comment: `var data2 = data; data2[0] = "Three;"`

Comment: The only array here is `data`, which you never use, other than to pull out its 0th element.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One picture is worth a thousand words, so here is what's going on:

[image: Before and After]

The effect of the assignment of `"Three"` to `t2` is that before the assignment `t1` and `t2` referenced the same object, but after the assignment they reference different objects. Nothing else is going on here.

The situation would have been different if you had an array of *mutable* objects, and manipulated their value instead of setting their references. For example, imagine replacing the array of strings with an array of `StringBuilder` objects, and calling `t2.Replace("Two", "Three")` instead of the assignment. Now the effect would be different, because `t1`, `t2`, and `data[0]` would be pointing to the same object.

Comment: There's no need for 1000 words, just these: The only array in the OP's code is `data`, which is never used, other than to pull out its 0th element.

Answer (score 8):

Your question has nothing to do with arrays. Since your `data[0]` is `string` -and it is a reference type- it's value is `One`, you never change it's value. You just created an another string reference called `t2` and set point to same object with `t1` reference. After you changed this reference object to `"Three"`, but this won't effect to what `t1` refers.

Let's look at line by line your code;

```
var t1 = data[0];
```

With this line you created a string reference as `t1` and this points to `"One"` object.

```
var t2 = t1;
```

With this line, you create a new string reference as `t2` and this points to same object with `t1` which is `"One"`

```
t2 = "Three";
```

With this line, you create a string object called `"Three"` and your `t2` is reference this object. It doesn't point to `"One"` object *anymore*. But this *doesn't* effect to `t1` reference. It *still* points to `"One"` object.

That's why

```
Console.WriteLine(t2);
Console.WriteLine(t1);
```

prints

```
Three
One
```

Answer (score 7):

Strings are also reference types. So if you write:

```
var t1 = data[0];
```

You have declared a new variable `t1` that references to the same string as `data[0]`. After this you write:

```
var t2 = t1;
```

Now you have a new variable `t2` that references to the same string as `t1`. You now have one `String` object on the heap, and three references to this object: `data[0]`, `t1` and `t2`.

Then you write:

```
t2 = "Three";
```

After this statement, `t2` points to antoher string in the heap with the value `"Three"`. However, `data[0]` and `t1` still point to the same original string.

Answer (score 0):

Writing `t2 = "Three"` won't alter the value of t1 because the types are reference type, so they "point" to their data. By assigning to `t2` you're telling it to reference something else.

Liukewise, when you wrote `t2 = t1` you're just telling `t2` to reference the same thing as `t1`. Future assignments to `t2` will just make it reference something else.

Some languages, like C++, do have the ability for you to store a reference to another variables, so that when you change the reference you actually change what the other variable is.

Answer (score 0):

this program exactly behaving as you expecting.

```
void Main()
{
    abc[] data = new[] { new abc(){i=1}, new abc(){i=2} };

var t1 = data[0];
var t2 = t1;
// here is the difference 
// t2 is still pointing to its old location
// but i will point a new position.
t2.i  = 5 ; //assigning the new value to i
// but t2 still pointing to t1
//all will be identical now.
Console.WriteLine(t2);
Console.WriteLine(t1); 
Console.WriteLine(data[0]);


  // repeating like you.
  t2 = new abc() {i=444};
 //now you will see t2 is different form t1. because
 // now t2 pointing to a new object instead of t1.
 Console.WriteLine(t2);
Console.WriteLine(t1);


}

public class abc{
    public int i ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> when you assign one array reference variable to another, you are
>   simply making both variables refer to the same array. You are neither
>   causing a copy of the array to be created, nor are you causing the
>   contents of one array to be copied to the other.
>
> // Assigning array reference variables.

```
        using System; class AssignARef {
     static void Main()
     {
 int i; 
    int[] nums1 = new int[10];
     int[] nums2 = new int[10]; 
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
     nums1[i] = i;
     for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
     nums2[i] = -i;
     Console.Write("Here is nums1: "); 
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
     Console.Write(nums1[i] + " ");
     Console.WriteLine();
     Console.Write("Here is nums2: ");
     for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
     Console.Write(nums2[i] + " "); 
    Console.WriteLine(); nums2 = nums1; // now nums2 refers to nums1 
    Console.Write("Here is nums2 after assignment: "); 
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
     Console.Write(nums2[i] + " "); 
    Console.WriteLine(); // Next, operate on nums1 array through nums2. 
    nums2[3] = 99; 
    Console.Write("Here is nums1 after change through nums2: ");
     for(i=0; i < 10; i++) 
    Console.Write(nums1[i] + " ");
     Console.WriteLine(); 

}
 }
```

> o/p

```
Here is nums1: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Here is nums2: 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9
Here is nums2 after assignment: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Here is nums1 after change through nums2: 0 1 2 99 4 5 6 7 8 9
```